# loop with nanoTime()

Tags: android, audio, time, timer

I want to do the same as this code below, but using `System.nanoTime()` instead

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    bt.send("Start");

                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(1);
                        Thread.sleep(50, 0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    s.playSound();
                }           }
            , 0, 3000);
```

The idea is to run both methods `send()` and `playSound()` **one after another** (50 milliseconds after running send()), in a **periodic** interval of 3 seconds. 
The reason why i want to use `nanoTime()` is that Timers are not accurate, and playing audio from android devices has also some latency, and im seeking for accuracy and precision in time. i also tried doing it in separate threads but still have lot of delay.
So i tried changing the code to something like this:

```
    long t1=System.nanoTime();
            long t = t1;
            while(true)
            {
                long t2 = System.nanoTime();
                if(t2>=t1+3 seconds)
                    bt.send("Start");
                t1=t2;
                t3=System.nanoTime();
                if(t3>=t+3500 milliseconds)
                    playsound();
                t=System.nanoTime();
            }
```

of coure, it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea to use `while(true)` but that will never work. Generally this whole code block will never work.

Your original code had the right idea, using a `Timer`. But you can also use a `Handler` if you want. But I have to tell you: Timing this exactly will almost be impossible and you have to be careful with `nanoTime()`. There is no system on a normal smartphone that would even come close to being capable of measuring timespans of a few nanoseconds. Even milliseconds can be inaccurate.

Anyway 1 nanosecond = 0.000000001 second. I **highly** doubt that you require timing to be that precise. And just using `nanoTime()` doesn't add any accuracy to the measurement, just more potential for inaccuracy.

My point is: The original code was pretty much spot on and I seriously doubt that `Timer` is that inaccurate. Most likely you just think that it is inaccurate because of some other unrelated programming error.

I modified your code a little to test its accuracy, this is the code I used:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50, 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final long pause = end - start;
        final long interval = start - lastStartup;
        lastStartup = start;
        Log.i("Timing Tests", interval + " / " + pause);
    }
}, 3000, 3000);
```

And these are the results I got:

```
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 51
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 51
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3001 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3001 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 51
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3001 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3001 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
Timing Tests﹕ 3000 / 50
```

So in other words, the `Timer` is accurate to +-1ms. That's as accurate as it is going to get, not just on Android but on any OS. And that is so accurate that no user could ever notice this tiny difference.

So I guess what I am saying is: Your code already is as accurate as possible. If you have timing problems than they have nothing to do with the `Timer` or the `TimerTask`.

Comment: what im doing is likely to send a command from a phone to another via bluetooth , when received, the other phone starts recording. after 50 milliseconds the first phone sends an audio signal. the problem is when i evaluate the recorded signals at the same position, they dont start at the same time, i have at least 50 millisecond delay between each, and sometimes they are perfectly aligned. i tried testing bluetooth delay and it was also around 1/2 milliseconds.

Comment: That's pretty bad. Why doesn't the other phone send a signal back when it is ready to record and then the phone starts sending an audio signal?

Comment: besides the thread.sleep() method time is always variable and i can notice that while playing the sound. im using a nexus 7 android phone.

Comment: its the same thing, when receiving the command the phone immediately starts recording so there is a little margin before the sound comes out from the first phone. but the problem is on the first side, the sound is never received at the same time.

Comment: Why does it have to in sync in the first place? It will an can never be completely in sync, but it confuses me that this seems so important to you. And are you using `Thread.sleep()` a lot? You should **never** use `Thread.sleep()` and this `Timer` above is pretty much one of the only exceptions.

Comment: this synchronization  is a requirement in my project. no this is the only piece of code where is thread.sleep()

Comment: Well then you are going to fail, it is physically impossible for it to be completely synced. There is always going to be a delay, but that doesn't matter. It's just something the receiver has to handle.

Comment: exactly. if the delay is not that much random or if even i can tell the source of the delay then i can subtract it later

Comment: You don't seem to understand. The delay is random and always going to be different. You cannot compensate for it. It's just something the receiver has to handle, and it's not a problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
public void sleep(long millis, long nanos) throws InterrupedException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = millis*1000000 + nanos;
    while (System.nanoTime()-start<duration) {
        long remaining = duration - System.nanoTime() + start;
        Thread.sleep(remaining/1000000, remaining%1000000);
    }
}
```

And the periodic calls

```
while (!isCancelled()) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    send("Start");

    long toSleep = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - System.nanoTime() + start;
    sleep(toSleep/1000000, toSleep%1000000);
    s.playSound();

    toSleep = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) - System.nanoTime() + start;
    sleep(toSleep/1000000, toSleep%1000000);
}
```

Comment: That's some boolean that you can set to `false` to stop looping.

Comment: I doubt that this is more accurate. Most likely it is more inaccurate.

Comment: And the code is not correct anyway. If I copy it 1:1 then it gives a compile time error. You seem to have mixed up your variable types while copying to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've inverted conversion of time units. I just edited the post, could you test it again ?

Comment: I just measured it and his `sleep()` method is more than twice as inaccurate than just `Thread.sleep()` by itself. Don't use this code... Aside from the obvious - that it doesn't compile - the problem seems to stem from `nanoTime()` as I explained in my answer: "There is no system on a normal smartphone that would even come close to being capable of measuring timespans of a few nanoseconds. Even milliseconds can be inaccurate.". So trying to compensate for this with a method like this will surely fail. And my measurements confirm that.

Comment: the reason i wanted to use nanoTime() is because i read it takes time from a hardware Timer as a reference, though Timer() , TimerTask() and  currentTimeMillis() take time from servers (wall clocks) which is really inaccurate on milliseconds level.

Comment: @hanaa No that is not true. I can just repeat myself: "There is no system on a normal smartphone that would even come close to being capable of measuring timespans of a few nanoseconds. Even milliseconds can be inaccurate.". What `nanoTime()` returns is nothing more than just a guess. Such short time spans cannot be measured. And these timespans are so tiny that measuring them makes no sense anyway. You cannot get any more accurate than anything `Timer` etc provides. And as I have shown in my answer, it is basically 100% accurate.

Comment: i understand. this is really frustrating. even what you did up above (using currentTimeMillis()) doesn't really give the exact delay. ok what about developing in native? i mean sound generator and recording in NDK? does that reduce the latency?

Comment: What he says is true : for example playing a sound takes time, so measuring less than milliseconds doesn't make sense. As he pointed out, `Timer` might sometimes miss a millisecond, but when is it really important ? You can also try `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` that might be more precise.